# SAP Vora 1.2 - Reading Vora tables from HANA

Tags: hana, vora

!!! UPDATE !!!

Finally  after hours of looking into documentation I found the issue. It turns out that I lacked some parameters in Yarn configuration.

This is what I did:

1. Open the yarn-site.xml file in an editor or log in to Ambari web UI and select Yarn>Config.
   Locate the property "yarn.nodemanager.aux-services" and add "spark_shuffle" to its current
   value. The new property name should be "mapreduce_shuffle,spark_shuffle".
2. Add or edit the property "yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class", and set it to
   "org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService".
3. Copy the spark--yarn-shuffle.jar file (downloaded in the step Install Spark Assembly
   Files and Dependent Libraries) from Spark to Hadoop-Yarn class path in all the node manager
   hosts. Typically this folder is located in /usr/hdp//hadoop-yarn/lib.
4. Restart Yarn and the node manager

!!!!!!!!!!!

I'm using SAP Vora 1.2 Developer Edition with newest Spark Controller (HANASPARKCTRL00P_5-70001262.RPM). I loaded a table into Vora in spark-shell. I can see the table in SAP HANA Studio in "spark_velocity" folder. I can load the table as Virtual Table. The problem is that I cannot select, or preview the data in the table, because of the error:

> Error: SAP DBTech JDBC: [403]: internal error: Error opening the
>   cursor for the remote database  for query "SELECT
>   "SPARK_testtable"."a1", "SPARK_testtable"."a2", "SPARK_testtable"."a3"
>   FROM "spark_velocity"."testtable" "SPARK_testtable"  LIMIT 200 "

Here is my hanaes-site.xml file:

```
<configuration>
    <!--  You can either copy the assembly jar into HDFS or to lib/external directory.
    Please maintain appropriate value here-->
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.spark.yarn.jar</name>
        <value>file:///usr/sap/spark/controller/lib/external/spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.0-3485-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.server.port</name>
        <value>7860</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <!--  Required if you are copying your files into HDFS-->
     <property>
         <name>sap.hana.es.lib.location</name>
         <value>hdfs:///sap/hana/spark/libs/thirdparty/</value>
         <final>true</final>
     </property>
     -->
    <!--Required property if using controller for DLM scenarios-->
    <!--
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>/sap/hana/hanaes/warehouse</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
-->
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.driver.host</name>
        <value>ip-10-0-0-[censored].ec2.internal</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <!-- Change this value to vora when connecting to Vora store -->
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.hadoop.datastore</name>
        <value>vora</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>

    <!-- // When running against a kerberos protected cluster, please maintain appropriate values
    <property>
        <name>spark.yarn.keytab</name>
        <value>/usr/sap/spark/controller/conf/hanaes.keytab</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>spark.yarn.principal</name>
        <value>hanaes@PAL.SAP.CORP</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
-->
    <!-- To enable Secure Socket communication, please maintain appropriate values in the follwing section-->
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.ssl.keystore</name>
        <value></value>
        <final>false</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.ssl.clientauth.required</name>
        <value>true</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.ssl.verify.hostname</name>
        <value>true</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.ssl.keystore.password</name>
        <value></value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.ssl.truststore</name>
        <value></value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.ssl.truststore.password</name>
        <value></value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>sap.hana.es.ssl.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>spark.executor.instances</name>
        <value>10</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>spark.executor.memory</name>
        <value>5g</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <!-- Enable the following section if you want to enable dynamic allocation-->
    <!--
    <property>
        <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors</name>
        <value>10</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors</name>
        <value>20</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>spark.shuffle.service.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <final>true</final>
   </property>
<property>
         <name>sap.hana.ar.provider</name>
         <value>com.sap.hana.aws.extensions.AWSResolver</value>
         <final>true</final>
     </property>
<property>
        <name>spark.vora.hosts</name>
        <value>ip-10-0-0-[censored].ec2.internal:2022,ip-10-0-0-[censored].ec2.internal:2022,ip-10-0-0-[censored].ec2.internal:2022</value>
        <final>true</final>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>spark.vora.zkurls</name>
        <value>ip-10-0-0-[censored].ec2.internal:2181,ip-10-0-0-[censored].ec2.internal:2181,ip-10-0-0-[censored].ec2.internal:2181</value>
        <final>true</final>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

ls /usr/sap/spark/controller/lib/external/

```
spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.0-3485-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar
```

hdfs dfs -ls /sap/hana/spark/libs/thirdparty

```
Found 4 items
-rwxrwxrwx   3 hdfs hdfs     366565 2016-05-11 13:09 /sap/hana/spark/libs/thirdparty/datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   3 hdfs hdfs    2006182 2016-05-11 13:09 /sap/hana/spark/libs/thirdparty/datanucleus-core-4.1.2.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   3 hdfs hdfs    1863315 2016-05-11 13:09 /sap/hana/spark/libs/thirdparty/datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.2.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   3 hdfs hdfs     627814 2016-05-11 13:09 /sap/hana/spark/libs/thirdparty/joda-time-2.9.3.jar
```

ls /usr/hdp/

```
2.3.4.0-3485  2.3.4.7-4  current
```

vi /var/log/hanaes/hana_controller.log

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/sap/spark/controller/lib/spark-sap-datasources-1.2.33-assembly.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/sap/spark/controller/lib/external/spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.0-3485-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/05/12 07:02:38 INFO HanaESConfig: Loaded HANA Extended Store Configuration
Found Spark Libraries. Proceeding with Current Class Path
16/05/12 07:02:39 INFO Server: Starting Spark Controller
16/05/12 07:03:11 INFO CommandRouter: Connecting to Vora Engine
16/05/12 07:03:11 INFO CommandRouter: Initialized Router
16/05/12 07:03:11 INFO CommandRouter: Server started
16/05/12 07:03:43 INFO CommandHandler: Getting BROWSE data/user/17401406272892502037-4985062628452729323_f17e36cf-0003-0015-452e-800c700001ee
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CommandHandler: Getting BROWSE data/user/17401406272892502037-4985062628452729329_f17e36cf-0003-0015-452e-800c700001f4
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO VoraClientFactory: returning a Vora catalog client of this Vora catalog server: master.i-14371789.cluster:2204
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: searching for compat-sap-c++.so at /opt/rh/SAP/lib64/compat-sap-c++.so
16/05/12 07:03:48 WARN CBinder: could not find compat-sap-c++.so
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: searching for libpam.so.0 at /lib64/libpam.so.0
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: loading libpam.so.0 from /lib64/libpam.so.0
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: loading library libprotobuf.so
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: loading library libprotoc.so
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: loading library libtbbmalloc.so
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: loading library libtbb.so
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: loading library libv2runtime.so
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: loading library libv2net.so
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: loading library libv2catalog_connector.so
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CatalogFactory: returning a Vora catalog client of this Vora catalog server: master.i-14371789.cluster:2204
16/05/12 07:11:56 INFO CommandHandler: Getting BROWSE data/user/17401406272892502037-4985062628452729335_f17e36cf-0003-0015-452e-800c700001fa
16/05/12 07:11:56 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/12 07:11:56 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/12 07:12:02 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/12 07:12:02 WARN DefaultSource: Creating a Vora Relation that is actually persistent with a temporary statement!
16/05/12 07:12:02 WARN DefaultSource: Creating a Vora Relation that is actually persistent with a temporary statement!
16/05/12 07:12:02 INFO CatalogFactory: returning a Vora catalog client of this Vora catalog server: master.i-14371789.cluster:2204
16/05/12 07:12:02 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/12 07:12:02 INFO DefaultSource: Creating VoraRelation testtable using an existing catalog table
16/05/12 07:12:02 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/12 07:12:11 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/12 07:14:15 ERROR RequestOrchestrator: Result set was not fetched by connected Client. Hence cancelled the execution
16/05/12 07:14:15 ERROR RequestOrchestrator: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 0 cancelled part of cancelled job group f17e36cf-0003-0015-452e-800c70000216
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobCancellation(DAGScheduler.scala:1229)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleJobGroupCancelled$1.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:681)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleJobGroupCancelled$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:681)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleJobGroupCancelled$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:681)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobGroupCancelled(DAGScheduler.scala:681)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1475)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1850)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1921)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:900)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(CommandRouter.scala:383)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(CommandRouter.scala:362)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(CommandRouter.scala:362)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler.aroundReceive(CommandRouter.scala:204)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Also strange is this error:

```
16/05/12 07:03:48 INFO CBinder: searching for compat-sap-c++.so at /opt/rh/SAP/lib64/compat-sap-c++.so
    16/05/12 07:03:48 WARN CBinder: could not find compat-sap-c++.so
```

Because I have this file in the location:

ls /opt/rh/SAP/lib64/

```
compat-sap-c++.so
```

---

After changing com.sap.hana.aws.extensions.AWSResolver into com.sap.hana.spark.aws.extensions.AWSResolver now the log file looks different:

```
    16/05/17 10:04:08 INFO CommandHandler: Getting BROWSE data/user/9110494231822270485-5373255807276155190_7e6efa3c-0003-0015-4a91-a3b020000139
16/05/17 10:04:13 INFO CommandHandler: Getting BROWSE data/user/9110494231822270485-5373255807276155196_7e6efa3c-0003-0015-4a91-a3b02000013f
16/05/17 10:04:13 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:13 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:13 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:13 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:29 WARN DefaultSource: Creating a Vora Relation that is actually persistent with a temporary statement!
16/05/17 10:04:29 WARN DefaultSource: Creating a Vora Relation that is actually persistent with a temporary statement!
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO DefaultSource: Creating VoraRelation testtable using an existing catalog table
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO ConfigurableHostMapper: Load Strategy: RELAXEDLOCAL (default)
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO HdfsBlockRetriever: Length of HDFS file (/user/vora/test.csv): 10 bytes.
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO ConfigurableHostMapper: Load Strategy: RELAXEDLOCAL (default)
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO TableLoader: Loading table [testtable]
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO ConfigurableHostMapper: Load Strategy: RELAXEDLOCAL (default)
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO TableLoader: Initialized 1 loading threads. Waiting until finished... -- 0.00 s
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO TableLoader: [secondary2.i-a5361638.cluster:2202] Host mapping (Ranges: 1/1 Size: 0.00 MB)
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO VoraJdbcClient: [secondary2.i-a5361638.cluster:2202] MultiLoad: MULTIFILE
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO TableLoader: [secondary2.i-a5361638.cluster:2202] Host finished:
    Raw ranges: 1/1
    Size:       0.00 MB
    Time:       0.29 s
    Throughput: 0.00 MB/s
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO TableLoader: Finished 1 loading threads. -- 0.29 s
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO TableLoader: Updated catalog -- 0.01 s
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO TableLoader: Table load statistics:
    Name: testtable
    Size: 0.00 MB
    Hosts: 1
    Time: 0.30 s
    Cluster throughput: 0.00 MB/s
    Avg throughput per host: 0.00 MB/s
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:04:29 INFO TableLoader: Loaded table [testtable] -- 0.37 s
16/05/17 10:04:38 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/05/17 10:06:43 ERROR RequestOrchestrator: Result set was not fetched by connected Client. Hence cancelled the execution
16/05/17 10:06:43 ERROR RequestOrchestrator: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 1 cancelled part of cancelled job group 7e6efa3c-0003-0015-4a91-a3b02000015b
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobCancellation(DAGScheduler.scala:1229)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleJobGroupCancelled$1.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:681)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleJobGroupCancelled$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:681)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleJobGroupCancelled$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:681)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobGroupCancelled(DAGScheduler.scala:681)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1475)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1850)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1921)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:900)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(CommandRouter.scala:383)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(CommandRouter.scala:362)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(CommandRouter.scala:362)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler.aroundReceive(CommandRouter.scala:204)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I is still "not fetched by the client", but now it looks that vora loaded the table.

Anyone, some ideas how to fix it? The same error appears when I try to read Hive tables insted of Vora.

> Error: SAP DBTech JDBC: [403]: internal error: Error opening the
>   cursor for the remote database  for query "SELECT
>   "vora_conn_testtable"."a1", "vora_conn_testtable"."a2",
>   "vora_conn_testtable"."a3" FROM "spark_velocity"."testtable"
>   "vora_conn_testtable"  LIMIT 200 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after hours of looking into documentation I found the issue. It turns out that I lacked some parameters in Yarn configuration (don't know why this affected HANA-Vora connection).

This is what I did:

Open the yarn-site.xml file in an editor or log in to Ambari web UI and select Yarn>Config. Locate the property "yarn.nodemanager.aux-services" and add "spark_shuffle" to its current value. The new property name should be "mapreduce_shuffle,spark_shuffle".
Add or edit the property "yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class", and set it to "org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService".
Copy the spark--yarn-shuffle.jar file from Spark to Hadoop-Yarn class path in all the node manager hosts. Typically this folder is located in /usr/hdp//hadoop-yarn/lib.
Restart Yarn and the node manager

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue and solved right now!
Its cause is that HANA cannot understand worker node's host names.
Spark controller send HANA worker node names, which has Spark RDDs.
If HANA doesn't understand their host names, HANA cannot get result and the error occurs.

Please check hosts file on HANA.

Comment: Hi,

Can you please provide me the exact steps you took to solve this issue?
Because I've tried to add host names (both public IP's and DNS names and private IP's and DNS names) to HANA /etc/hosts, but this still not solved my problem.

Regards,
Przemek.

Comment: Hi, We added IP's and DNS names. They are not only master nodes but also worker nodes. That's all we did and the issue solved.  After that, we faced another issue.  No Spark executor runs, so decreased "spark.executor.memory" parameter value, and Spark Controller works again.

Comment: So sadly, that solution do not work for me, also added IP's and DNS's on HANA but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

The log shows error `Result set was not fetched by connected Client. Hence cancelled the execution`. Client in this context is HANA trying to fetch from Vora.

The error could be caused by a connection problem between HANA and Vora.

1. The hanaes-site.xml shows `sap.hana.ar.provider=com.sap.hana.aws.extensions.AWSResolver`. This looks like a typo. Assuming you use the `aws.resolver-1.5.8.jar` that is included in the lib directory after deploying `HANASPARKCTRL00P_5-70001262.RPM` the correct path should be `com.sap.hana.spark.aws.extensions.AWSResolver`. See PDF document attached to [SAP Note 2273047 - SAP HANA Spark Controller SPS 11 (Compatible with Spark 1.5.2)](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/2273047)
2. Ensure that the necessary ports are open: See [HANA Admin Guide](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Administration_Guide_en.pdf) -> 9.2.3.3 Spark Controller Configuration Parameters -> ports 56000-58000 on all Spark executor nodes

If issues still occur, you could you check Spark executor logs for problems:

1. Start the Spark Controller and reproduce the issue/error.
2. Navigate to the Yarn ResoureManager UI at http://:8088 (Ambari provides a Quick Link via Ambari -> Yarn -> Quick Links -> Resource Manager UI)
3. In the Yarn ResourceManager UI click on the 'ApplicationMaster' link in column 'Tracking UI' of your running Spark Controller application
4. On the Spark UI, click on tab 'Executors'. Then for each of the executors, click on ‘stdout’ and ‘stderr’ and check for errors

Unrelated: Those parameters are deprecated with Vora 1.2 and you can remove them from hanaes-site.xml: spark.vora.hosts, spark.vora.zkurls

Comment: Could you check the Spark Executor logs. I added info on how to do that in the answer.

Comment: Hi,

I did everything as adviced, but have some trouble on p.3

When trying to click on "ApplicationMaster" I'm redirected to 

"http://secondary.i-ac361631.cluster:8088/proxy/application_1463733085774_0001/"

but not see anything because of chrome error:

"could not find DNS adress secondary.i-ac361631.cluster."

It is strange that AplicationMaster redirect to secondary cluster, as my spark controller is installed on master.

Comment: Your computer does not know the AWS-internal hostname. You can either adopt your hosts file on your computer or change the URL to the public AWS IP address of that node. Also, did you have a look at Fukuhara's answer w.r.t. making the Vora hostsnames known to HANA?

Comment: Yes, but with no luck.

I've looked into errors as you adviced and found this one, caused by YARN:

Remote Root Log Dir [/app-logs] already exist, but with incorrect permissions. Expected: [rwxrwxrwt], Found: [rwxrwxrwx]. The cluster may have problems with multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for couple of days and this is caused by ports being blocked on the Spark controller. We are running this environment on AWS and I was able to resolve the error by updating the Spark host's security groups and opening ports 7800-7899, after which HANA was able to see the HIVE tables in SDA.

Hope this helps someone, someday :)